# Does anyone have some references on using metal halide lamps in a greenhouse?

Tags: light, greenhouse

I am looking for some references to use metal halide lamp in a greenhouse. What specifications should I look for in a lamp?

Comment: Brand and supplier are going to be off-topic because we don't do shopping recommendations. But I suspect we can help find a good greenhouse light

Comment: Pretty much wattage and color temp.

Comment: does some one has an idea for this lamp purpose?

Comment: Are you looking for nightime lighting, or are you actually trying to provide the plants with all their light from this?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified your application of the light, which is an important detail, so here's a useful listing of 4 common modes of lighting. When shopping for your metal halide light, remember that 1 lx = 1 lm/m2, or 1 lux equals 1 lumen divided by 1 square meter. Then you can use the listing below to judge whether any lamp in question has the output capacity fitting to your needs.

- Deep shade (too low for the average plant to thrive) is about 1,000 lux.
- Normal house lighting is about 60-100 lux.
- Full daylight (not full sun) (good for shade loving plants) is about 10,000–25,000 lux.
- Direct sunlight (ideal for most plants) is about 32,000–100,000 lux.